# App Store submission thoughts/issues

Tags: iphone, app-store, google-play

**App Store**

We have been developing an app for quite some time now for a company, we're at the moment planning for the application to be submitted to the app store within a few weeks.

Lets say that the application will have around 10000 users.

Now, the application is meant to be used by the company's own clients, as they will be the only ones able to log in on said app.

Is an app, such as this, supposed to be deployed on the app store or is it supposed to be deployed using an enterprise license?

Will this cause any complications?

**Android Market**

Lets also say that said company wants us to develop same said app but for Android, and publish it to the Android Market.

Will google have any problems with an app that will only have selected users?

This has long been a nailbiter for me and also; said company knows more or less NOTHING about smartphone development.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is an app, such as this, supposed to be deployed on the app store or is it supposed to be deployed using an enterprise license?

If it's for clients, app store. The enterprise program is for distributing apps to employees.

You'll have to provide the reviewers with a test account that they can log in with, but it should be ok on the app store from what you've said.